# Java Graphics2D g2.drawLine is adding dots/coordinates, not drawing lines

Tags: java, graphics2d

I'm trying to write code that draws several lines based on commands of character arrays (strings).

In my example, F means move down, + means rotate counterclockwise, and - means rotate clockwise.

In my result, only the first line is drawn.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI73h.png)

The result of the lines only show the coordinates.

My code is below.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Draw extends JFrame{ //extends JFrame to help construct appropriate GUI

    int angle = 0;
    Graphics2D g2;

    public static void main(String[] args) { //main method
        Draw d =new Draw();
        d.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);  // fixes the immediate problem.
        this.g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Coordinate s, e;
        s = new Coordinate(450, 450); 
        this.currentCoordinate = new Coordinate(450, 490);

        // this line is drawn!
        g2.drawLine(s.x, s.y, this.currentCoordinate.x, this.currentCoordinate.y);

        for (char c : "FFF+F-F".toCharArray()) {
            String character = String.valueOf(c);
            paintBasedOnSymbol(this.currentCoordinate, character);
        }
    }

    private Coordinate paintBasedOnSymbol(Coordinate c, String s) {

        switch(s) {
            case "F":
                c.setY(c.y + 10);
                c.setX(c.x + this.angle);
                // any lines triggered here are not drawn!
                g2.drawLine(this.currentCoordinate.x, this.currentCoordinate.y, c.x, c.y);
                break;
            case "+":
                this.angle += 15;
                break;
            case "-":
                this.angle -= 15;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        this.currentCoordinate = c;

        return c;
    }

    public Draw(){ //constructor used to directly implement the frame UI
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setSize(900,900);

        JButton button =new JButton("press");
        panel.add(button);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //make sure program stops when window is closed
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't perform custom painting this way.  Use a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method instead.  You'll end up with a lot less issues

Answer (score 0):

Rubber duck debugging is real :) I figured out the issue

If you have this problem, don't edit the original coordinate's x/y values.

Create new ones.

i.e. I replaced

```
            c.setY(c.y + 10);
            c.setX(c.x + this.angle);
```

with

```
new Coordinate(c.x + this.angle, c.y + 10);
```